# getting an error with my closing curly brackets

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, curly-braces

i am getting an error saying it's expecting a comma in place of a curly bracket but when i do what is suggested i get another error saying it can't match the curly braces now.

```
if (page === "Goexploring") {
      axios
        .get(process.env.NATIONAL_PARK_API_URL)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          let hikingActivity = [];
          response.data.data[0].parks.forEach((parks) => {
            let output = "";
            hikingActivity.forEach((parks, index) => {
              output += `${parks.states}: ${parks.states[activities]}, `;
            return parks.states === "TN";
          })
          console.log(hikingActivity);
          state.Goexploring.parks = hikingActivity;
          done();
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      }
    }),
  },
});
```

have adjusted things adding commas, braces and taking out braces and commas and still getting an error. maybe someone will see it differently. lol

Comment: Side note: `forEach` doesn't return anything. It operates on arrays in place.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it like this:

```
if (page === "Goexploring") {
    axios.get(process.env.NATIONAL_PARK_API_URL).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        let hikingActivity = [];
        response.data.data[0].parks
            .forEach((parks) => {
                let output = "";
                hikingActivity.forEach((parks, index) => {
                    output += `${parks.states}: ${parks.states[activities]}, `;
                    return parks.states === "TN";
                });
                console.log(hikingActivity);
                state.Goexploring.parks = hikingActivity;
                done();
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });
}
```

The **bracket pair colorizer** (vscode extension) can help you for finding the errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correctly formatted code:

```js
if (page === 'Goexploring') {
  axios
    .get(process.env.NATIONAL_PARK_API_URL)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      let hikingActivity = [];
      response.data.data[0].parks.forEach((parks) => {
        let output = '';
        hikingActivity.forEach((parks, index) => {
          output += `${parks.states}: ${parks.states[activities]}, `;
          return parks.states === 'TN';
        });
        console.log(hikingActivity);
        state.Goexploring.parks = hikingActivity;
        done();
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Another thing you should have a look at is your usage of `forEach`. As per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value), `forEach` does not return anything. You may wan't to check out [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) if you want to build an array for example.

Comment: yeah i am trying to work on an API returning a state and the national parks within that state. thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to help. Please make sure to mark the question as answered. Thanks!

Comment: oops i think i missed part of what was wrong in the first post lol.